# Interpolate a GeoJSON file

Tags: geojson, interpolation

I have a GeoJSON file which consists of rainfall data in a location.

I want to interpolate those point data in GeoJSON and make a raster file, and display in Leaflet map. How can I do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you want to do the interpolation using python?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Interpolation, raster conversion, and Leaflet mapping are all broad topics independently. Please [Edit] your Question to focus on one task, explain what you have tried, and what problem you have encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use QGIS then interpolate with the existing processing tools. Here is an example:

[image]

You could then convert your map to a website using QGIS2Web plygin in either Leaflet, OpenLayers or Mapbox preserving your GeoJSON layer. You do not have to convert it to a raster, even though you could.

[image]

However, be informed that if your layer is too bog that would affect the web performance.

Comment: I would rather use something like https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/spatial_analysis_interpolation.html as an example. The contour extraction example does not answer the question.

Comment: You could that method as well.